# copy few columns from another workbook to the current workbook and current sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy few columns from another workbook to the current workbook and current sheet,but I am getting a subscript out of range error.I want to know if something is wrong

```
Sub CopyColumns()
Dim SourceRange As Range
Dim DestRange As Range


On Error GoTo myerror
Set SourceRange = Workbooks("Invoice.xlsx").Worksheets("working").Columns("A:G")
Set DestRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("working").Range("A:G")


SourceRange.Copy DestRange


myerror:
If Err > 0 Then MsgBox (Error(Err)), 48, "Error"
End Sub
```

Comment: Which line throws the error?

Answer (score 0):

I tried this code out and it looks like it copies everything just fine. What might be happening is that your sheet might have a misspelling. Another thing that would cause that error is the worksheet your referencing could be named different or might have a different extension.